# How to paginate in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I've followed this documnetation
(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination)
and made changes accordingly but still I am not able to paginate the required page.

This is my controller code:

```
public function showManageCourierAddress()
{

    $viewdata = [];
    $addressRepoObj = new \App\Repositories\Mongo\CourierAddressRepository();
    $addressData = $addressRepoObj->getAddressList(0,(int)Session::get('organisation_id'));
    $viewdata['addresslist'] = $addressData;
    unset($addressData);
    
    return view('frontend.admin.managecourieraddress', ['viewdata' => DB::table('viewdata')->paginate(15)]);
}
```

On the view laravel, I've added this :

```
{{ $viewdata->links() }}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? And what I should do?

Comment: Does this work `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`? Seems to be correct from what you've shown.

Comment: What you get when calling `{{ $viewdata->links() }}`?

Comment: You forget to add `Request` parameter as `public function showManageCourierAddress(Request $request)`

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('viewdata')->paginate(15)
```

returns `LengthAwarePaginator` instance, which implements [these methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods).

It is enought to call `{{ $viewdata->links() }}`, and it should return whole html with pagination buttons and links. You just write some styles for existing classes, or use methods as mentioned above to create your own html with your own structure.

If I did not understand your problem, please reply in comment.